# why does the login and password popup appear when you search for ajax using the api admin in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I made an ajax search for blogs, and for action I use Admin API:

```
/admin/api/2022-07/blogs/{blog_id}/articles.json
```

I also, use action to get metafields:

```
/admin/articles/{articles_id}/metafields.json
```

But the problem is that when I do a search from a mobile device, I keep getting a popup asking for login and password (screenshot).

[image]

Why does this happen?

Could it be because of using Admin API? right now the site has a domain like `test-site.myshopify.com`.

Will this problem be solved if the site has a permanent domain?

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT do Admin API calls from any front-end, mobile, desktop, who cares. That is a huge security violation as it plasters your secret token all over the internet for anyone to pilfer and use. If you want to make Admin API calls from your store, use App Proxy. It is the only way.